# Collect facebook geolocated restricted posts via the api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, geolocation

Does anybody know how to collect all geolocation restricted posts for a facebook account trough the facebook graph API?

thanks

Comment: you mean to say that you want to collect the posts which the user made restricted to a particular place?

Comment: @Coding-Freak, yes that is correct.